# Using LibGdx isAnimationFinished() correctly to time animations

Tags: animation, libgdx, game-development

We are working on a university project using Gdx to create a game. I've been working on animations since the begining, but I've had problems running animations without a loop.
I want to run a sparkle animation of 6 frames when I pick an item, which should run when the level is complete and the door diseapears.

```
elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); //Tiempo de juego
        
        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(floor,160,160);
        game.batch.draw(walls,128,160);
        game.batch.draw(door,370,640);
        if(!levelComplete){
            game.batch.draw(gate,384,640);
        }else{
            if(!game.gameAnimations.itemPickUp.isAnimationFinished(elapsedTime)){
                game.batch.draw((TextureRegion) game.gameAnimations.itemPickUp.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime,false),400,500);
            }
        }
        game.batch.end();
```

I've tried multiple iterations of the isAnimationFinished, specificaly changing the elapsed time, or changing where in the code I implement the drawing method.
I either:

1. Get the animation running really slow.
2. The animation runs for one frame and is covered by the map
3. If I pick the item fast it works, but if i wait to long it doesn't play.

I'm sure that I'm missunderstanding the stateTime I'm suposed to use with the ifAnimationFinished method, but I haven't been able to find information online, and I also don't know how to get the precise starting time of the animation.

Comment: You need to put the code for isAnimationFinished and getKeyFrame, the code iyou include with the question isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

Since your animation does not loop, your start and finish are controlled by you, really. Think of your animation's stateTime as independent of most everything else. You said your animation is 6 frames, and when you create your animation, you need to tell libGDX how long each frame is. So (example only), maybe you do:

yourAnimation = Animation< TextureRegion> (0.05f, yourFrames);

which would make a total animation time of 0.05 x 6 = 0.30

When you are ready to "start" your animation, you *then* set your stateTime (think separate variable just for your animation) to 0, each render call add deltaTime and figure out where in the animation you are.

//somewhere outside your render step, initialize

stateTime = 0f;

// inside your render step, if its time to do your animation:

stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

currentFrame = yourAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime);

Your animation will now play based on stateTime, which you started at 0 when you wanted the animation to begin, and each render step adds a bit to stateTime. This is how getKeyFrame knows which frame you want. Since you don't want to loop, you know the animation will be completed after 0.30 (the example from above), or if you really want, you can call yourAnimation.isAnimationFinished(stateTime) to see if it IS complete. I suppose its your choice. Either option would let you know if you've hit the end of the animation, and then you need to do whatever you want at that point in your game.

The key point is you have to control the stateTime variable, and make sure it is 0 when *you* start the animation playing.